docker - hdfs to hive issue
I have configured three containers that are networked because I intend to utilise Hadoop with Hive. You can access the Docker setup via https://github.com/jcool12/hadoophive/tree/main/hadoophive to download the folders/files needed to run it. Before you build and execute docker-compose up, please run this command via your command line (e.g. terminal):
export HIVE_VERSION=4.0.0. 

This export above ensures that when it builds Hive, it will know which version to use. The Hadoop, Hiveserver2, Metastore, and Postgres start successfully. On Hiveserver2, without both core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml, I can access Hiveserver2 on port 10000 by executing this command:
winpty docker exec -it hiveserver2 beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/'

Within Hiveserver2, I aim to access the HDFS on the Hadoop container, as I need to load data from HDFS into a table within Hive. If I add both core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml in Hiveserver2's /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/, restart Hiveserver2, and then attempt to connect to Beeline again, it refuses the connection, hence it fails to connect due to the addition of these XML files. Could you please assist in making HDFS accessible within Hiveserver2 and ensuring that Hive is accessible on port 10000, enabling me to run HiveQL queries, etc.?
Update:
I updated the core-site.xml with the inclusion of this below in core-site.xml for both hadoop and hiveserver2 containers, but still not worked:
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
        <value>*</value>
    </property>

